# moment.js convert eastern daylight time to utc?

Tags: javascript, timezone, timestamp, momentjs

I have the following function that adds 30 business days to a date. I'm passing in `UTC` but the output gives me `eastern daylight time` What can I do to get only UTC out of this function? I've tried `moment(tmpDate).utc()` but nothing seems to work. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
function addBusinessDays(date, daysToAdd) {
        var cnt = 0;
        var tmpDate = moment(date);
        while (cnt < daysToAdd) {
            tmpDate = tmpDate.add('days', 1);
            if (tmpDate.weekday() != moment().day("Sunday").weekday() && tmpDate.weekday() != moment().day("Saturday").weekday()) {
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
        }

        return tmpDate._d;
    }

    var tmp = addBusinessDays("Tue Apr 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 30);
```

Comment: you are converting string to normal date...not utc date

Comment: I honestly don't have much of an idea what I'm doing here. I'm pretty confused right now. How could I get that into a utc date?

Comment: Read the docs...there's a UTC section https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: Real helpful. I wouldn't of posted this if I haven't already looked there...

Comment: @JoeScotto - I think he is suggesting you need to try `var tmpDate = moment.utc(date);` instead. He's only trying to help.

Comment: @Darren I understand he's trying to help but someone with 110k reputation shouldn't just link to documentation. I'm trying that right now but it does not seem to work at all. The output of tmpDate._d is still in eastern standard time.

Comment: @JoeScotto - You asked about UTC, How are users supposed to know you read the docs or not. Also, you should really avoid using private properties (`._d`). You tried just returning tmpDate ? If you use moment.utc() instead and then console.log(tmpDate._isUTC) you would see that the date IS now utc. _d is an internal property which is likely just a local version of the date.

Comment: Yes, if I return tmpdate it does not have any utc in it at all.

Comment: @JoeScotto - You may find this helpful: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charlie pointed out, you are creating a local date. Moment, by default creates local dates.

So a couple of small changes to your function

```
function addBusinessDays(date, daysToAdd) {
        var cnt = 0;
        var tmpDate = moment.utc(date); // call utc to create a UTC date
        while (cnt < daysToAdd) {
            tmpDate = tmpDate.add('days', 1);
            if (tmpDate.weekday() != moment().day("Sunday").weekday() && tmpDate.weekday() != moment().day("Saturday").weekday()) {
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
        }

        return tmpDate.toDate(); // call toDate() to get the JS date out of Moment. Do not use internal private properties.
    }
```

Now when you call this, you will get a JS date object back. By default it will be local, that's just how they work. However, you can call toISOString on your JS date to get the UTC representation of the date.

```
var tmp = addBusinessDays("Tue Apr 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 30);
console.log(tmp.toISOString());
```

Comment: I'd also add that if you want a string representation, then it is easier to just call `.toISOString` or `format` from the moment object.  Additionally, with the string you gave as the input example, a warning will occur because no format was specified.